# Compiling external libraries for a terminal programs?

Tags: java

How can I compile terminal programs which uses external libraries? I'm using JColor (https://github.com/dialex/JColor) to color my font but I don't know how to compile it.

My IDE is IntelliJ. I already tried to compile my program into a jar but executing it in terminal ignores JColor. No error but no color and cryptic symbols instead. I don't know if it's cause of JColor or I missed something during compiling.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Edit : The real issue

(See replies)

We found the issue not to be related to imports, but rather that ANSI control support is disabled within windows terminals by default, but enabled within IntelliJ.

This made it seem as though the library was not working after being exported, or wasn't being exported.

[Relavent Discussion](https://github.com/dialex/JColor/issues/54)

### The dependancy

InteliJ gives the option to export libraries with the module from within the `Project Structure` window:

[image]

Assuming the library is configured within your project, all you have to do is navigate to `Project Structure > Modules > myModule > Dependencies`where you can add the library, and tick `export`

### The artifact

Next, create an artifact from your module, *with depenencies*

[image]

The output layout shows the internal layout of the jar after export, check the library is in there.

[image]

Now when you build your artifact, it should contain the dependency.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I didn't work tho. Here are my settings: https://i.ibb.co/GTn3PkD/fgfdg.png

Comment: That looks good, I just tested it with that same maven dependency, copied your setup, and it exported great - The extracted dependency appeared under `out/artifact/artifact.jar/com/diodonunes/jcolor`. 


Unfortunately, i'm not quite sure why it wouldn't export with your configuration

Comment: I can also find the dependency after extracting the jar but still doesn't format my text. I'm using `java -jar "path of jar file"` in cmd to run the jar. Is this maybe the mistake? IntelliJ console displays it correctly but not Windows 10 terminal.

Comment: Hmm, is it possible that whichever terminal that is running the programme doesn't support the formatting? Edit: Just checked the repo, it only shows it being demo'd in powershell, could you try it in there?

Comment: @apk_gringo I also found an issue [in the repo](https://github.com/dialex/JColor/issues/54) which suggests that ansi control support in windows terminals are disabled by default

Comment: Thank you very much! This one really worked.

Answer (score 0):

1. javac -cp /path/to/jar/file Design.java
2. java -cp .:/path/to/jar/file Design

[image: Try this code]

So, lets suppose your current working directory in terminal is rc/structure/